# Applying CSS to Table rows

Tags: css, rows, css-tables

I've got this table:

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='trip'>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='trip'>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and I'd like to colour rows who have a class of `trip`

How do I use trip with tg which is assigned to the table ?

I've created a simple fiddle showing this.
https://jsfiddle.net/sagsb415/1/

Comment: Remove the space so its `.tg tr.trip {`

Comment: If you want advice on how to correct your CSS then please post the CSS that isn't working here in your question. Don't rely on people following links elsewhere to make sense of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a space in your fiddle between `tr` and `.trip`. Try this.

```
.tg tr.trip {
    padding:5px 5px;
    background-color:#8600b3;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sagsb415/2/

Comment: Thanks this resolved it and explained what I'd done wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.tg .trip td{
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

write directly in your style-sheet for trip class

```
 .tg .trip {
    padding:5px 5px;
    background-color:#8600b3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following css:

```
.trip >td{
background-color:red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.tg tr.trip {
  padding:5px 5px;
  background-color:#8600b3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```css
.tg tr.trip {
  background: #f6c;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
    <th>123456</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='trip'>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
    <td>876543</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
    <td>AABBCCDD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='trip'>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
    <td>abcdef</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped.